Android with Gradle fails in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I'm trying to build an Android application with the Gradle task in an Azure DevOps pipeline

but i either get this error (i also tried Gradle@3)

Or when I'm trying to specify java version (jdkVersionOption) it doesn't work, no matter what java version i try)

The agent has java 19, but also when i try to do java tool installer for any version of java, it doesn't work either (preinstalled)

I'm also beginner at this so please make is simple for me :)

Hi @roteki, welcome to SO :-) Please paste the code and error messages as text, not images. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

it says "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Something in your build is using Java 8 (maybe the rust sdk). Either add Java 8 to your Agent or find out what is using it and see if you can update. ( you could share the rustsdk build.gradle that might show the issue)

@roteki did you found any solution? I am facing with the same error on Gradle 8.7

If your requirement is to build your app with JDK8 and you haven't installed JDK8 in your self-hosted agent environment, you can use the JavaToolInstaller@0 task to install the expected JDK. However, you shouldn't use Preinstalled as jdkSourceOption, because it is designed to use Java versions that are pre-installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent.
Here is a sample pipeline for your reference. (See more information on JavaToolInstaller@0 - Java tool installer v0 task | Microsoft Learn.)
variables:
  system.debug: true

pool:
  #vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  name: Self-hostedAgentPoolName
  demands:
    Agent.OS -equals Linux

steps:
- script: |
    java -version
    wget https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk/8u402-b06/openlogic-openjdk-8u402-b06-linux-x64.tar.gz -O JAVA_HOME_8_X64.tar.gz
    tree
  displayName: Download JDK8
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'JAVA_HOME_8_X64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/JAVA_HOME_8/X64'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
    createExtractDirectory: false
- script: |
    java -version
    echo Environment Variable JAVA_HOME_8_X64 is $(JAVA_HOME_8_X64)
    tree $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Check JDK version

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'clean build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false




thanks for the explanation but i have already fixed that part by upgrading java and gradle. but now i'm stuck into a new problem. Here is the scan link if you can help me with it https://scans.gradle.com/s/qnjxwq7buk62u/failure#1

i'm currently using Gradle 8.7 and when i ran your pipeline i have received this error again https://dev.azure.com/nadamajd/a57302b0-a613-48ab-ab09-69c1867f7f38/_apis/build/builds/701/logs/10

@roteki, Glad to know the issue in this post is resolved. Per the new problem please use a new thread to investigate further. Thx.
